# Represent expression calculation c++ (Polymorphism design)

Tags: c++

I want to implement a very simple expression calculator in C++, for example, to calculate

> (3 + 2) * 8

So, I have made a base class for expression like this:

```
class Expression {

 public: 
  virtual ~Expression() {}

  // Returns the result of evaluating this expression.
  virtual float eval() const = 0;

  // Prints the expression. DO NOT evaluate before printing.
  virtual void print() const = 0;  
};
```

And then, to represent numbers, which I only care about INT and FLOAT, I've made this:

```
/*
 * Number
 */
class Number : public Expression {

};

class IntNum : public Number {
public:
    IntNum(int num) : m_value(num) {}
    ~IntNum() {}

    float eval() const {return (float) m_value;}
    void print() const {std::cout << m_value;}
protected:
    int m_value;
};

class FloatNum : public Number {
public:
    FloatNum(float num) : m_value(num) {}
    ~FloatNum() {}

    float eval() const {return m_value;}
    void print() const {std::cout << m_value;}
protected:
    float m_value;
};
```

At last, I want to represent ADD, which need two operand:

```
/*
 * Two oprand expression
 */
class TwoOpndExp : public Expression {
public:
    TwoOpndExp(Expression* exp1, Expression* exp2) : m_exp1(exp1), m_exp2(exp2) {}
    ~TwoOpndExp() {}
protected:
    Expression* m_exp1;
    Expression* m_exp2;
};

/*
 * Add expression
 */
class AddExp : public TwoOpndExp {
public:
    float eval() const;
    void print() const;
};
```

Here is the problem: I write

> TwoOpndExp(Expression* exp1, Expression* exp2) : m_exp1(exp1), m_exp2(exp2) {}

because nobody knows what is at the both side of "+", it can be a number, simply like "1+2", or expressions involved, like "1+(2^3)". So I think the type of para for constructor should be Expression*. 
But, when I test it like:

```
  IntNum* x = new IntNum(3);
  FloatNum* y = new FloatNum(4.1);
  AddExp* add = new AddExp(x, y);
```

the compiler said no constructor found for

> AddExp* add = new AddExp(x, y);

I know the class will hold something as para list to find a right constructor, but, just to this problem, how to design to make it right?

This problem is available onsite:

> http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-088-introduction-to-c-memory-management-and-c-object-oriented-programming-january-iap-2010/assignments/

see ass5

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot inherit constructors. If you want to call the base class constructor, you must explicitly define a constructor that then delegates to the base class.

Comment: Why so much pointers (in the class and outside too)? I don't see why you need any pointer here, and it's more problematic than without.

Comment: joel cornett is right. To inherit the non default (or parametrized) contructors from the base class, one must implement it in the derived class too and may delegate to the base class. For reference check this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Object_construction_improvement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add another constructor:

```
AddExp(Expression* exp1, Expression* exp2) : TwoOpndExp(exp1, exp2) {}
```

Without this, the `TwoOpndExp` constructor is not inherited and therefore not available.